# Cors issue in ionic 4

Tags: http, ionic-framework, cors, http-headers, cache-control

I have ionic project that use request-promise to connect a soap service but when do the request got this error:
    Request header field cache-control is not allowed by Access-Control- 
    Allow-Headers in preflight response.
I google this problem and all of the resource says this error shouldn't happen in mobile device but I get this error in real device

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Modify the SOAP service *must* set the correct CORS headers. You need the `Access-Control-Allow-Header` header and make sure `Cache-Control` is included.
- The alternative in this case to make sure that your client doesn't set the `Cache-Control` header.

Comment: I don't access to SOAP service and in client side I comment the Cache-Control from the headers request but didn't work. I'm wondering why get this error in mobile device? this error must happen when app run in the browser not mobile device